# testing tkinter-based function on jenkins in a docker container on AWS

Tags: docker, jenkins, tkinter, amazon-ec2, x11

I have a python code that passes all the test on my local machine. The code uses tkinter and provides a GUI. However, none of the test functions actually open the GUI. (They call tk.Tk() though).

I created a docker container locally and could use X11 forwarding to pass the tests on the "local" container as well.

Now, I'm trying to run the tests on Jenkins that I have set up on an EC2 instance. Jenkins is supposed to create a docker container using the Dockerfile that is on my repository. And then call "docker run -e ... -v ..." (similar to what I had in my local computer) to check the tests. I understand my ec2 instance does not have a gui and therefore x11 forwarding is not as simple as it was on my computer. There should be a way for tests using a gui to be checked through Jenkins setup on AWS. Any help is appreciated.

**EDIT**
Here is the build script that I have on AWS, it creates the docker container using the Dockerfile:

```
IMAGE_NAME="test-image"
CONTAINER_NAME="deidentifier_clinical"
echo "Check current working directory"
pwd
echo "Build docker image and run container"
docker build -t $IMAGE_NAME .
echo $DISPLAY
docker run -v /tmp/.X11-unix:/tmp/.X11-unix -e DISPLAY=unix$DISPLAY $IMAGE_NAME bash -c "cd /$CONTAINER_NAME;make test"
echo "Copy coverage.xml into Jenkins container"
rm -rf reports; mkdir reports
docker cp $CONTAINER_NAME:/deidentifier_clinical/htmlcov/* reports/.
echo "Cleanup"
docker stop $CONTAINER_NAME
docker rm $CONTAINER_NAME
docker rmi $IMAGE_NAME
```

This fails on the *docker run* line. This same script runs with no problem on my local computer after setting up the X11-forwarding.

Comment: you should focus on one issue per question, so you have to choose which one you want to ask about (tkinter or tests on jenkins), but most importantly you should provide a [mre]

Comment: I appreciate your response. Sometimes however it's not as easy to separate these problems, since as I mentioned, I can run the tests separately. I can create the docker, I have the jenkins running. But it's the combination of these that gives me the problem.